# Data Store in single line but I want to store it one by one in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have create a random number generator which generate number using timestamp and some random alphabet. i have design it to generate multiply value like if you want to generate 10 values you have to write 10 in unit field and it will generate 10 values everything works fine till here but when i try to store the value in Firebase realtime database its appears in a single line with 
 tag what i was getting is like this `gb2r142b559971e<br>gb2r1421c555a14<br>gb2r142bc11493e<br>`.
And i want it like this.

```js
{
  gb2r142b559971e
  gb2r1421c555a14
  gb2r142bc11493e
}
```

This is the code. for this

```js
  var unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
  var all = '';
  // i = 0
  
  for(var j=0; j<unit; j++)
  {
    var ts = String(new Date().getTime()),
    i = 0,
    out = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < ts.length; i += 3) {
        out += Number(ts.substr(i, 2)).toString(36);
    
    }
      var ans = Math.random().toString(15).slice(5);
      var para = (out + ans);
      
      all += (para.slice(0, 15))+'<br>';
        
  }            

  //return all; 

  console.log(all);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = all;
  
  
//This is how I was storing the value  
      app.ref('/All_Chassis/'+all).set({
  Model:Model.value,
  DOM:DOM.value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database doesn't modify the value that you store in it. But the Firebase console might not display the newlines as you expect to see them. If that is what you're experiencing, I recommend simply ignoring such values in the console and only checking them in your application.

Comment: got the solution just used `set` under loop with some changes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution just used `set` under loop with some changes and it is works as expected.

```js
      var unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
      var all = '';
      var all2 = '';
      // i = 0
      const Model = document.getElementById('Model');
      const output = document.getElementById('output');
      const DOM = document.getElementById('DOM');
      for(var j=0; j<unit; j++)
      {
        var ts = String(new Date().getTime()),
        i = 0,
        out = '';

        for(var i = 0; i < ts.length; i += 3) {
            out += Number(ts.substr(i, 2)).toString(36);
        
        }
          var ans = Math.random().toString(15).slice(5);
          var para = (out + ans);
          var data2 = (para.slice(0, 15));
          app.ref('/All_Chassis/'+ data2).set({
            Model:Model.value,
            DOM:DOM.value
        })
          all += (data2 )+'<br>';
          all2 += (data2 ) + '\n'
      }            
    
      //return all; 
    
      console.log(all);
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = all;
```